# Java how to start up the GUI made with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have made a simple GUI using IntelliJ-IDEA and I can't figure out how to start it up. Something like `Form1 f = new Form();` inside my `main()` function doesn't seem to do anything. Does anyone know how to start it up ?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        Form1 t = new Form1();
    }
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Did you call  `setVisible(true)`?

Comment: @hexafraction Where exactly is that option ? Intellij-idea has affiliated a `GUI Form` file type named Form1 with a `Form1.java` class file and a `Form1.form`  file which opens through their interface. So, I simply tried to call `Form1 f = new Form();`. Process just exits with code 0 though. What exactly are you suggesting ? How would I call `setVisible(true);` ? Why would that not be true by default ?

Comment: You could either call that in the form's constructor, or depending if the form is made by extending a `JFrame`, call `f.setVisible(true)`.

Comment: @hexafraction Have you used intellij-sense before ? [This](http://i.gyazo.com/2ca2d5c8915cdb2c64e0744f13e38fdd.png) is all the code inside the auto-generated `Form1.java` file. Making a constructor inside this class and trying to call `setVisible(true);` didn't work because this method doesn't exist.

Comment: I have used the form builder on an older version, and I've never seen it create it in that way. Is there a helper class or some sort being generated?

Comment: @hexafraction I added a screenshot and everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add a couple of lines more than expected. Here is how my working code looks like for the `Form1.java` file. I didn't change my `main()` fucntion.

```
public class Form1 extends JFrame {

    // ******** These are just auto-generated from the IDE ********
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton bb137;
    private JButton button3;
    private JButton button4;
    private JButton button5;
    private JButton button6;
    private JButton button7;
    private JCheckBox checkBox1;
    private JRadioButton radioButton1;
    private JRadioButton radioButton2;
    private JRadioButton radioButton3;
    // ************************************************************

    public Form1(){
        super("Whatever form title here.");
        // panel1 is my main panel as you can see in my question's screenshot
        setContentPane(panel1); 
               //x , y, width, height
        setBounds(300,300,600,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```